# C#: How to convert long to ulong

Tags: c#, long-integer, ulong

If i try with BitConverter,it requires a byte array and i don't have that.I have a Int32 and i want to convert it to UInt32.

In C++ there was no problem with that.

Comment: Somewhat confused what you're asking here buddy - longs, byte arrays, and ints - can you elaborate ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A simple cast is all you need. Since it's possible to lose precision doing this, the conversion is explicit.

```
long x = 10;
ulong y = (ulong)x;
```

Comment: Isn't this possible to overflow with big negatives?  You can use `unchecked` to truncate instead: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a569z7k8(VS.71).aspx

Answer (score 7):

Try:

```
Convert.ToUInt32()
```

Answer (score 7):

Given this function:

```
string test(long vLong)
{
    ulong vULong = (ulong)vLong;
    return string.Format("long hex: {0:X}, ulong hex: {1:X}", vLong, vULong);
}
```

And this usage:

```
    string t1 = test(Int64.MinValue);
    string t2 = test(Int64.MinValue + 1L);
    string t3 = test(-1L);
    string t4 = test(-2L);
```

This will be the result:

```
    t1 == "long hex: 8000000000000000, ulong hex: 8000000000000000"
    t2 == "long hex: 8000000000000001, ulong hex: 8000000000000001"
    t3 == "long hex: FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF, ulong hex: FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF"
    t4 == "long hex: FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE, ulong hex: FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE"
```

As you can see the bits are preserved completely, even for negative values.

Answer (score 2):

To convert a long to a ulong, simply cast it:

```
long a;
ulong b = (ulong)a;
```

C# will NOT throw an exception if it is a negative number.

Comment: I  don't beleive that this throws an exception with a negative value, but will not be what you expect...  don't have .net on here (laptop), or would test it.

Comment: It won't, but the first bit will be interpreted as the most significant bit instead of the sign bit.

Comment: It won't throw. You should consider revise your answer otherwise it could be misleading.

Comment: @KFL indeed. Updated.

Comment: If it throws or not is a compiler settings (Build/Advanced/Check for arithmetic overflow/underflow). To be safe you should always wrap it like `ulong b = unchecked((ulong)a)`

Answer (score 1):

```
Int32 i = 17;
UInt32 j = (UInt32)i;
```

EDIT: question is unclear whether you have a long or an int?

Comment: I think John is referring to "old" longs in C or C++ that were 32 bits wide.

Comment: I meant that he referred to it out of habit.