# Convert a .NET long to an unsigned 8-byte integer

Tags: .net, long-integer, unsigned-integer

For the purposes of setting a value in Active Directory I would like to convert a long to an unsigned 8-byte integer, for assignment to an AD property.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple cast can cause problems if the long is negative and may result in an OverflowException. You'll need to use the [unchecked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a569z7k8(VS.71).aspx) syntax to ensure it is cast properly.

```
ulong myUnsignedValue = unchecked( (ulong)originalLongValue );
```

Answer (score 0):

Cast the `long` to a `ulong`.

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/688667/c-how-to-convert-long-to-ulong).